# How to make tarot card display and drag unit in Flutter

Tags: flutter, responsive-design, drag-and-drop

How can I code the Flutter app to list the cards like in the picture and how can the user drag and drop one of the cards into the box?

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vevwO.jpg)

When I did it with the draggable widget, I lost the scrolling feature and could not list my cards as seen in the picture.